# Pass a variable out of LWC into Flow Current stage

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, visual-workflow

Trying to change a lightning flow current stage from a LWC component that is inside the flow. I have multiple screens in the LWC component that can't be separated in separate LWC components. I need to be able to change the flow stage from within the LWC component that is within the Flow.

This doesn't work as $Flow.CurrentStage is an Object and can't be filled by a String. I don't see a way to do this as Object type is not accepted in lightning_FlowScreen parameters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear if the LWC component is inside the flow.  If it is then you can pass an attribute back to the flow from the LWC component and then use a decision element to choose the next step in the flow.

If the LWC component is outside the flow, but for instance on the same page then I don't think you can do this - you might experiment with events on the page, or platform events to be sent and received by having two LWC, one on the screen and one in the flow.   But I would think that this is a very complex way to solve the problem and a completely different approach might be required - e.g. replace the flow completely with a LWC and have then talking to each other.

Hope this helps you find a solution.